# Format-List or Format-Table with property of multiple variables

Tags: powershell

If I have multiple variables and I want to pull certain properties from all of them in a single view (for instance their Count), how would one do this?

For example, if I want something like the following

```
# Table Format
Name               Count
Variable1          $Variable1.Count
Variable2          $Variable2.Count
Variable3          $Variable3.Count

# List Format
Name      : Variable1
Count     : $Variable1.Count

Name      : Variable2
Count     : $Variable2.Count

Name      : Variable3
Count     : $Variable3.Count

# Variables are ArrayLists, hence the Count property
```

I thought this would be fairly trivial using the standard select-object, format-list or format-table cmdlets and use of calculated properties, but I just cannot get it to work as expected.

This was my first thought:

```
Format-List @{N='Variable1';E={$Variable1.Count}}, @{N='Variable2';E={$Variable2.Count}}
```

I guess those cmdlets cannot be called without piping something to them first, so then I tried the following, and it did what I wanted, however it seems to keep looping endlessly, outputting the results over and over and over.

```
@($Variable1, $Variable2) | Format-List @{N='Variable1';E={$Variable1.Count}}, @{N='Variable2';E={$Variable2.Count}}
```

Is there something stupid/simple I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a dynamic sense of approach, `Get-Variable` could be a good option if I'm understanding you correctly. This passes over the name, and the value which you'd be able to use a calculated property to convert over to the values sum/count:

```
$variable1 = 1..10
$variable2 = 5..15
$variable3 = 10..20
Get-Variable -Name variable1,variable2,variable3 | 
    Format-List -Property Name, @{
        Name = 'Count'
        Expression = { $_.Value.Count }
    }
```

With `Format-List` it will output:

```
Name  : variable1
Count : 10

Name  : variable2
Count : 11

Name  : variable3
Count : 11
```

...and with `Format-Table`:

```
Name      Count
----      -----
variable1    10
variable2    11
variable3    11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic method.  I create a table with random names like Variable25.  the table contains 10000 rows with the name having number between 1 and 100.  Then Group by name to get counts

```
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
for($i = 0; $i -le 10000; $i++)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $number = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 100
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue ("Variable" + $number)
   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null 
}
$groups = $table | Sort-Object -Property Name | Group-Object {$_.Name}
$tableCount = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($group in $groups)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue $group.Name
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Count -NotePropertyValue $group.Count
   $tableCount.Add($newRow) | Out-Null 

}
$tableCount | Format-Table
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, however the accepted solution is much more simple thus I accepted it.

Comment: When you have a limited number of items to count, listing the specific ones is simpler.  When you have hundreds of items it is not practical to hardcode each name.  My code is more complicated because most of it is to create test data.  My code is 7 instructions compared to 2 instructions.